# Access specific cookies by domain/name in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox extension and need to access a specific cookie from a specific domain. I have this code which fetches all cookies for all domains, how do I request only the cookie that I am looking for.

```
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");

var cookieManager = Cc["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"].getService(Ci.nsICookieManager);

var count = cookieManager.enumerator;

while (count.hasMoreElements()){
    var cookie = count.getNext();
    if (cookie instanceof Ci.nsICookie){
        console.log(cookie.host);
        console.log(cookie.name);
        console.log(cookie.value);
    }
}
```

To sum up, I am able to find the cookie that I am looking for with the code above but I don't want to have to iterate through all of the cookies from all domains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`nsICookieManager2` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookieManager2) (the original `nsICookieManager` interface was frozen and couldn't be changed which is why this extended version was created):

```
var cookieManager = Cc["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"]
                      .getService(Ci.nsICookieManager2);
var count = cookieManager.getCookiesFromHost("example.com");
```

Note: the concept of frozen interfaces was dropped in Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4). Since then some interfaces similar to `nsICookieManager`/`nsICookieManager2` have been unified - so in a future Firefox version `nsICookieManager2` might go away as well, all the functionality will be exposed on `nsICookieManager` then.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how to fetch the cookies from iterator that `getCookiesFromHost` returns?

Comment: A complete example can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Cookies

Comment: @Wladimir Palant Is there a way to remove all the cookies from firefox extension?

Comment: @muthu: How about using [nsICookieManager.removeAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsICookieManager#removeAll%28%29)?

Comment: Is there a way to obtain all the cookies of firefox browser instead of getting cookies based oh hostName

Comment: @muthu: Well, if you don't want to read the documentation - how about reading the text of this question?