# Access a secure cookie from a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: firefox, cookies, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, cookie-httponly

Is there anyway to access a secure cookie from a Greasemonkey script?
I wrote script that uses the `document.cookie.split` function. It returns a list of cookies but it doesn't included the secure cookie(s).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and possibly modify a cookie with a userscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749907/how-can-i-access-and-possibly-modify-a-cookie-with-a-userscript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you really mean **cookies with [the `HttpOnly` attribute set](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.6)**. (See, also, [Wikipedia for HttpOnly cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie).)
In that case, you cannot access these cookies from Greasemonkey because they are forbidden to JavaScript, and because Greasemonkey does not provide an alternate mechanism to see them.

You can try making [a feature request](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues), but I'm not optimistic about its reception. (Try anyway.)

[Firefox add-ons, *can* work with these cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16496212/331508), so you can fork [the Greasemonkey source](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey) yourself or write a helper add-on ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617164/331508)) to get to these cookies.

---

If you mean **cookies with [the `Secure` attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.5)** (Cookies that must be [sent only over HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie)), then I *believe* you can access those from [injected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485122/accessing-variables-from-greasemonkey-to-page-vice-versa/13485650#13485650) code in the target page scope, but I'm not set up to test this at the moment.  (The target page must be loaded over HTTPS and on the exact same domain as the cookies you want.)

Comment: i tested accessing document.cookie directly from the console, using `console.log(document.cookie)`
and then accessing it via an injected script using the following code

`text="console.log(document.cookie)" ;x=document.createElement('script');x.textContent=text;document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(x)`

both methods produced identical results (neither method revealed the HTTP only cookies)